# ORMlite + MySQL Foreign Key Binding

Tags: java, mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship, ormlite

How do I create auto delete cascade using ORMLite? I am using ormlite-core and omlite-jdbc version 4.8. I tried

```
public class Account {

    // for QueryBuilder to be able to find the fields
    public static final String NAME_FIELD_NAME = "name";
    public static final String PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME = "passwd";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = NAME_FIELD_NAME, canBeNull = false)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME)
    private String password;
}
```

and another class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "orders")
public class Order {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD_NAME = "account_id";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD_NAME,
         canBeNull = false,index = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true,
         columnDefinition = "integer references document(id) on delete cascade")
    private Account account;

    @DatabaseField
    private int itemNumber;

    @DatabaseField
    private int quantity;

    @DatabaseField
    private float price;
}
```

But When I delete the parent key record, no exception is being thrown and also, if try to insert records in order table with foreign key values which are not defined in the Account table, no exception is being thrown and the records get created and inserted in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But When i delete the parent key record , no exception is being thrown and also , if try to insert records in order table with foreign key values which are not defined in the Account table, no exception is being thrown and the records get created and inserted in database .

Stupid answer but shouldn't the column definition be:

```
integer references account(id) on delete cascade
```

I assume that the `Account` table is named `account` and not `document`.  Otherwise your SQL looks good.

I would take a look at the schema on the MySQL side to make sure that it matches what you are expecting.  I'd also try some inserts from the MySQL command line to see if you can figure out what is going on outside of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).

Hope this helps.